Hyundai Tuscon Door Opens Only After Multiple Attempts
I have a Hyundai Tuscon 2016 that is lately having a problem with the front passenger door where the door cannot be opened from the outside after being unlocked with the fob. Here's what I could find out:

Only happens when locked and unlocked
Tugging on the handle several times works sometimes
Opens in one go from the lever inside
No apparent issue with the locking mechanism as I can see the lock button move when using fob

I tried to push the metal cable that operates the lock, from the inside, after watching some YouTube videos but it doesn't seem to have helped.

From your description, it would seem to me the problem lies in the linkage between the outer door handle and the lock, but wouldn't know for sure. If there is any slop at the cable connections, you may be having the issue you're describing.
